# Make HTML readable again

Tags: php, html, tags, newline, summernote

I have some HTML code in a file created by an online JS editor

`<h1>Title</h1><p>Some text</p><p>Some text</p>`

that is not easily readable offline.
I'd like to split it like this with php, that is more readable

```
<h1>Title</h1>
<p>Some text</p>
<p>Some text</p>
```

I can make a string replace adding the newline after each closure, but if I save several times it adds newlines every time I save.

Do you have any suggestion?

Thank you.

P.S. the online JS editor is Summernote, maybe there is a config to work around this?

Answer (score 1):

what you looking to is "**unminify** html",there is some online tools can do the work **like:**

- [unminify.com](http://unminify.com/)
- [textfixer.com](https://www.textfixer.com/html/uncompress-html-code.php)

Comment: Do you know of any PHP script to do it? Thank you

Comment: @GiorgioBorgonovo Asking for third party scripts or off site resources are off topic in SO. I suggest that you try Google.

Comment: @GiorgioBorgonovo you can use php [DOM](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php)-elements [parse HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

Following the suggestions of Mohamed, I found Tidy.

Tidy comes with both a shell command (http://tidy.sourceforge.net/) and a PHP library (http://php.net/manual/en/book.tidy.php), both of them work very well and provide sereal tools to maintain HTML code.